# How to get components of a template in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

I am newbie in Tridion. I am looking for some sample code for a TBB to get all components for a component template. I have seen examples of how to get components of a page or from a folder but not for this.

I could get the count by using `object.GetListUsingItems(filter).SelectNodes(*).Count` in my template, but I need a way to iterate all components and get Title or other attributes of Components.

Please advise.

Comment: Please read the descriptions for the Stack Overflow tags before tagging your questions. Of the 5 tags you selected only one applies to your Question.

Comment: Are you trying to get components associated/published using dynamic component template?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get all components for a template in one go, you need to look first at which Schemas are associated with this component template, then get all components for each schema. Be aware of Blueprint contexts when doing this.

I'm slightly confused as to what you're trying to achieve with this, if you want to do this as part of a publishing action you would very quickly end up with massive publish transactions with many components in it.

If you want more attributes than exposed in Lists, then use `GetUsingItems` instead - but be aware that this is a considerably slower operation with a lot more database interactions than getting a list.